# MongoDB /data/db/ does not exist but did before

Tags: mongodb

Last night I went to bed and everything was fine. I woke up today and connection to the DB couldn't be established. So I rebooted, ran `mongod --repair` and got this error

```
 ERROR: dbpath (/data/db/) does not exist.
 Create this directory or give existing directory in --dbpath.
 See http://dochub.mongodb.org/core/startingandstoppingmongo
```

But this all worked fine, so I tried to cd into the folder /data/ and that folder doesn't exist. I used all of the default settings when setting up Mongo, it worked great for two weeks and now this. When the heck happened?

Comment: By default mongodb looks for ```/etc/mongodb.conf``` What is your dbpath?

Comment: just opened up both /etc/mongodb.conf and /etc/init/mongodb.conf
 both files exist but are blank. My dbpath was what ever the default path mongo made it.

Comment: dbpath: "/var/lib/mongodb"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You probably have a config file, by default it is usually `/etc/mongodb.conf`.

Try `mongod --config /etc/mongodb.conf --repair`

Comment: ran that and got "all output going to: /var/log/mongodb/mongodb.log
" re-ran "mongod --repair" and still same error

Comment: Your dbpath is defined in `/etc/mongodb.conf`.  Did you see any error messages in the log?  Did you try starting the service after running `--repair` the way I suggested?

Comment: when I run  `mongod --config /etc/mongodb.conf --repair`, I get `all output going to: /var/log/mongodb/mongodb.log` when i run `mongod --config /etc/init/mongodb.conf --repair`, I get `error command line: unrecognized line in 'limit nofile 20000 20000'
use --help for help`

Comment: sifitng through my logfile to today, I'll comeback with the results in a moment.

Comment: Hey, It looks like this is the only error I'm getting: `Mon Feb 10 10:33:43.198 [initandlisten] need to upgrade database local with pdfile version 4.5, new version: 4.5`. Here is my logfile if you'd like to see it: `http://107.170.247.56/mongo.html`

Comment: Ohh and `dbpath: "/var/lib/mongodb"` so should I run `mongod --dbpath /var/lib/mongodb`?

Comment: `mongod --dbpath /var/lib/mongodb --repair` will show the output on the command line.

Comment: still can't connect. Still getting this error. `ERROR: dbpath (/data/db/) does not exist.
 Create this directory or give existing directory in --dbpath.
 See http://dochub.mongodb.org/core/startingandstoppingmongo`

Comment: use the init script, don't start it manually.  `service mongodb start`

Comment: Awesome! I added `mongod --dbpath /var/lib/mongodb` to my `/etc/rc.local` so that's how it will always start-up. Thank You!

Comment: I added `dbpath=/var/lib/mongodb` assuming that would do the trick. But you literally have to start it up everytime with `mongod --dbpath /var/lib/mongodb`. Just found out one of my co-workers power cycled the server from the switch last with no good reason and that was probably why the .config files were blank. Thank you leif for all of your help!